# systemd/NetworkManager - DNS server ordering

Tags: linux, dns, systemd, networkmanager

My debian installation is using `systemd-resolved` and NetworkManager. For my home connections, I've configured NetworkManager to set the DNS servers to use:

```
$cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my-wifi-ssid.nmconnection

...
[ipv4]
dns=10.30.20.1;1.1.1.1;8.8.8.8;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto
...
```

Basically I'd like to use my onsite DNS server at `10.30.20.1` by default, and have the other two for fallback only.

Problem is, the active/used server appears to be selected seemingly at random:

```
$resolvectl status
Link 4 (wlp3s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
       DNS Servers: 10.30.20.1 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Note I've seen all three as active, but it's not consistent.
Is there a way to force systemd-resolved to prefer the server listed first by NetworkManager?

Comment: Is there a functional difference between the servers, or do you just need fallback in case the internal server goes down?

Comment: The preferred one resolves bunch of names on my LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Even with static DNS servers configured, NetworkManager will occasionally delete all of them and leave none working.  Also, it will change your DNS servers as network interfaces go up and down.  There doesn't seem to be a way within NetoworkManager to turn off its dynamic management.

An alternative solution is to disable dynamic management of DNS entirely.
You can do this by deleting the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink and replace it with a real file that is static.  Something like this would work:

```
nameserver 10.30.20.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

There are other settings in this file that NetworkManager automatically adds, you might want to copy those as well.

Comment: That's no good. I'll need different setup when I'm in the office. Or connected to company VPN.

Comment: If you are mobile, this is not a good solution, but without it you just have to put up with the whims of NetworkManager.